# Use a async function from the angularjs factory

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I want to use the first customer of my customers in my Controller, but its not working. What i want is to retrieve my first customer in a factory service and then use it in my Controller.

```
.factory("CustomerService", ["$resource", function($resource) {
      return $resource('js/customers.json');
   }])

   .factory("FirstCustomer", ["CustomerService", function(CustomerService) {
      var customer;
      customer = CustomerService.query().$promise.then(function(info) {
         console.log(info[0]); // This works
         return info[0];
      });
      console.log(customer); //This doesnt
      return {
         value: customer
      };
   }])

   .controller('CustomerController', function($scope, FirstCustomer) {
      $scope.customer = FirstCustomer.value;
      console.log($scope.customer); // Shows Object { $$state: Object }
   })
```

I know that `Object { $$state: Object }` means, that the Object could not be resolved in time. But how can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

The `value` should be function.

In your case when you call `$scope.customer = FirstCustomer.value;` you immediately go to `console.log($scope.customer);` because you get object.

Make `value` to be a function and promise resolving will happen properly.

I would write factory as:

```
.factory("FirstCustomer", ["CustomerService", function(CustomerService) {
            var customer;

      var factory = {  
        value: function () {                
            var customer = CustomerService.query().$promise.then(function(info) {     
            return info[0];
           });

          return customer;
        }     
      };
      return factory; 
    }])
```

---

**2nd option (shorter)**

```
.factory("FirstCustomer", ["CustomerService", function(CustomerService) 
{
  var customer;   

 return {
   value: function(){
          customer = CustomerService.query().$promise.then(function(result) {                 
              return result.data.results[0];
          });
          return customer;
          }        
     };
 }])
```

Usage:

```
$scope.customer = FirstCustomer.value();
```

<kbd>[Similar Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1tmnrhL/)</kbd>

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. But i still got an Object { $$state: Object }. Not sure what is wrong. I try to figure it out.

Comment: Its also in the JSFiddle. console.log($scope.data) is also an Object { $$state: Object }.

Answer (score 0):

catch the result in the controller like this

```
.controller('CustomerController', function($scope, FirstCustomer) {
    FirstCustomer.value().then(function(info) {
        $scope.customer = info
        console.log($scope.customer);

    });
})
```

Comment: SO asks to get `value` but not promise like in your case. However this solution will work too. Just case of where do you want to resolve it in Service or in Controller

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.controller('CustomerController', async function($scope, FirstCustomer) {
      $scope.customer = await FirstCustomer.value;
      console.log($scope.customer); // Shows Object { $$state: Object }
   })
```

use async await from ES6 javascript